# How long would Earth be habitable after being knocked out of orbit?

Tags: astrophysics

Let’s say a rogue planet or something came close enough to Earth to knock it out of its orbit. Whatever event causes this, can this happen without disrupting human life in the short term and how long can I stretch this period where life is mostly the same? I figure at some point society will collapse, but I’d like write about the moments before that.

I’m interested in a realistic answer, and a bonus question is: could this event happen in a  way where the moon stills orbits the earth? Or at least still follows the earth as it gets further and further from our sun.

Comment: Even better:  [The earth is flung into deep space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38728/the-earth-is-flung-into-deep-space)

Comment: Please take our [tour] and read our [help] to better understand our site. Also, please take the time to search the vast number of questions that have already been asked here. Your question is likely already answered with one or more of the following: [[1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/137615/40609)], [[2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/38775/40609)], [[3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/191255/40609)], [[4](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/137585/40609)], [[5](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/215708/40609)]. Search for "rogue earth" for more.

Comment: Also, please take the time to read the tag wikis before you use them. You're using the [tag:reality-check] tag incorrectly, so I removed it. It's purpose is for you to provide one or more world rules and a situation that implements the world rule(s), giving us a chance to check the reality of your worldbuilding efforts (read: consistent use of the rules). It's specifically not for asking if something is realistic.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You should read "A Pail of Air" by Fritz Leiber, I always think of that short story whenever anyone asks this question, thought of it this time too but couldn't remember what it was called or who it was by earlier and only just now found it in my co!lection .. given answers on other versions of this question it likely contains significant inaccuracies but still a good read with some interesting survivalist ideas for a once habitable frozen rogue planets to play with at its core.